# Jupyter fails to start Python 3 kernel after a conda environment was removed

Tags: python-3.x, macos, anaconda

I just removed a conda created environment (`nltk`) and now my iPython kernel is stuck on the removed conda environment.

Every time, I launch jupter notebook, the kernel fails to start and pops up with this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/mysterio/anaconda3/envs/nltk/bin/python': '/Users/mysterio/anaconda3/envs/nltk/bin/python'
```

I inspected the kernel json file in

```
/Users/mysterio/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json
```

and here's the output:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/Users/mysterio/anaconda3/envs/nltk/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

Quite clearly, the deleted conda environment still controls the iPython kernel which is weird because I have removed it.

How do I restore the default kernel behaviour?

Thanks in advance.